# Can I use this coolant in a Toyota Camry 2003 with water?

Tags: maintenance

Can I use 'Coolelf Auto Supra' in my Toyota Camry 2003? And can I use that coolant in combination with water?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should use what the owner's manual recommends for this engine.

Comment: For those who VTC as off-topic, this question is just asking if the product is compatible with their vehicle. This is no different than asking if a vehicle usually using Premium fuel can use Regular instead, or if a vehicle can use synthetic oil instead of regular dino oil.

Answer (score 1):

Requirements for newer Toyota vehicles are usually "ethylene
glycol based nonsilicate, non-amine, non-nitrite, and non-borate engine coolant with long-life hybrid organic acid technology". You first need to check whether my guess was correct from the owner's manual, and then check the specifications of the coolant.

I would be rather safe than sorry, and use genuine Toyota coolant.

Based on the data sheet, it looks like the coolant may be already premixed and ethylene glycol based, so no need to add water. And there is no nitrite or boron or silicates. It's unclear whether the coolant is non-amine. Organic additives are mentioned, but I am unsure whether this means they are organic acids. It seems to be a long-life coolant.

Answer (score 0):

[Coolelf Auto Supra](http://www4.total.fr/asia-oceania/singapore/automotive_lubricants/Passenger%20Car/Antifreeze%20and%20Coolants/Readymix%20Coolant/Coolelf%20Auto%20Supra%2037%5EC.pdf) can be mixed with demineralized water. The data sheet doesn't mention compatibility with the Toyota Camry, but it lists the specifications it meets. You should check the owner's manual for the coolant specifications of your car.